# Google Apps Script - Open link from Menu items

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to open new window/tab with specified URL directly after clicking on add-on's [menu item](http://screencast.com/t/eNlhLwxka)? Something similar to window.open().

Comment: No, there isn't, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. Show a small gui that shows the anchor.
Even if you put the link on a cell it still needs two clicks.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for how to do this then realized I had an old menu item that already did it! So figured I'd add an answer here since it was the first result that came up in my search. Credit goes to someone else, I had found this solution a couple years ago and saved it.

```
function menuItem(){
  var url = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/';
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<html><script>'
  +'window.close = function(){window.setTimeout(function() {google.script.host.close()},9)};'
  +'var a = document.createElement("a"); a.href="'+url+'"; a.target="_blank";'
  +'if(document.createEvent){'
  +'  var event=document.createEvent("MouseEvents");'
  +'  if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")>-1){window.document.body.append(a)}'                          
  +'  event.initEvent("click",true,true); a.dispatchEvent(event);'
  +'}else{ a.click() }'
  +'close();'
  +'</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  +'<body style="word-break:break-word;font-family:sans-serif;">Failed to open automatically. <a href="'+url+'" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.</body>'
  +'<script>google.script.host.setHeight(40);google.script.host.setWidth(410) </script>'
  +'</html>')
  .setWidth( 90 ).setHeight( 1 );
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog( html, "Opening url... make sure the pop up is not blocked." );
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer because it is (now?) possible with this code.  The only thing lacking is the code for creating the menuItem, which is easily found with a Google search.